# Select children and siblings of :not selector

Tags: html, css, children, siblings

I would like to style everything in a document like this:

```
body * { color:#000; }
```

But I would like to exclude the style from a certain div and everything that it holds, so I tried the not selector like this:

```
body *:not(.thisdiv *) { color:#000; }
```

It doesn't seem to work, what else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

In your given example there's isn't a problem. Any styles set on `body` should not override comparable styles on `.thisdiv` because of specificity.

Comment: When I set the "all(*)" selector on thisdiv the whole styling doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Running a few tests, I found that `:not` doesn't seem to work on the `body` element, unless I'm missing something.

You could keep it simpler and so something like this:

```
div:not(.thisdiv) {color: #000;}
```

but that's not quite the same as what you had. You can, of course, override any body color with this:

```
.thisdiv {color: #222}
```

which is better supported by browsers anyway and is pretty standard.